# AngularJS: How to place enter animation for each element on ngView

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is there a way to animate each content of the ngView rather than the View(div) itself upon entering?

Comment: I dont think so and that wont be a good idea also

Comment: why? can you please enlighten me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to animate than writing custom CSS for the animations using the transition apis eg (transition: all linear 0.5s;) 
of CSS either you animate ng-show/ng-hide or using ng-view
Here is something from the official angularjs api docs:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  Choose:
  <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
  <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
  <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>

  <div class="view-animate-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />

  <pre>$location.path() = {{main.$location.path()}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{main.$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.params = {{main.$route.current.params}}</pre>
  <pre>$routeParams = {{main.$routeParams}}</pre>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.view-animate-container {
  position:relative;
  height:100px!important;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.view-animate {
  padding:10px;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter, .view-animate.ng-leave {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;

  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border-left:1px solid black;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  padding:10px;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter {
  left:100%;
}
.view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left:0;
}
.view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:-100%;
}
```

Source:  [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: if i understand correctly you are trying to achieve something similar to this: http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1

Comment: sorry but no.. for example i have a template that has multiple divs.. i want the divs to enter individually maybe with just a delay